# Class inherited with list and exception when try to read it

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

### Original Question

I have this situation:

```
type
  X1 = Class
  protected
    oMyList: TMyList; 
  public
    property MyList: TMyList write oMyList;
  end;

  X2 = Class(X1)
  public
    procedure GetMyList;
  end;
```

with:

```
  procedure X2.GetMyList;
  begin
    Writeln (oMyList.Count);    // <-- Return exception
  end;
```

and in main program:

```
var
  P: X2;
  MyList: TMyList;
begin
  P := X2.Create;
  try
    P.MyList := MyList;
    P.GetMyList;
  finally
    P.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is an exception when I try to read `oMyList.Count`. Of course, `MyList` is created and defined correctly.

Where is my mistake?

### Updated Question

I have this situation:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;

// Module 1

type
  PDBEstr = Integer;  // Just an example of list with integer
  TDBEstr = TList<PDBEstr>;

  TArchive = class
  protected
    oDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Free;
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read oDBEstr;
  end;

constructor TArchive.Create;
begin
  oDBEstr := TList<PDBEstr>.Create;
  oDBEstr.Add(36);  // Add an element to list
end;

destructor TArchive.Free;
begin
  oDBEstr.Free;
end;

// Module 2

type
  TX0 = class
  protected
    oArchive: TArchive;
    function GetDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Free;
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read GetDBEstr;
  end;

constructor TX0.Create;
begin
  oArchive := TArchive.Create;
end;

destructor TX0.Free;
begin
  oArchive.Free;
end;

function TX0.GetDBEstr: TDBEstr;
begin
  Result := oArchive.DBEstr;
end;

// Module 3

type
  TX1 = class
  var
    oDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read oDBEstr write oDBEstr;
    procedure Load;
  end;

procedure TX1.Load;
begin
  writeln (oDBEstr.Count);  // Return 1
end;

// Module 4

type
  TX2 = class(TX1)
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TX2.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  // In this point i need to have access to oDBEstr for work with data
  // in oDBEstr
  writeln(oDBEstr.Count);   // <----- Return Exception
end;

// Main Program

var
  X0: TX0;
  X2: TX2;
begin
  try
    X0 := TX0.Create;
    try
      writeln(X0.DBEstr.Count);  // Return 1
      writeln(X0.DBEstr.First);  // Return 36
      X2 := TX2.Create;
      try
        X2.DBEstr := X0.DBEstr;
        writeln(X2.DBEstr.count);  // Return 1
      finally
        X2.Free;
      end;
    finally
      X0.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

All work perfectly, only in `TX2.Create` I have exception when I try to read `oDBEstr`. Of course, I take as example `TX2.Create`, but I need to have access to `oDBEstr` in all TX2, not only in `TX2.Create`.

Comment: Done, but not solve. I continue to receive exception: "Access violation at address XXXX in module XXXX. Read of address: XXXX"

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, David spotted the error.

Comment: Is oMyList created in X1 or X2?  If it is created in X1 is the constructor virtual?  Is inherited called in the constructor of X2?  So many questions to ask when you do not show us the code that actually creates the list.

Comment: @Marcello A couple of points of Stack Overflow convention. Your edit changed the question completely. By removing the original question you made my original answer look completely out of place. I restored the original question. Edits to questions should clarify and provide more detail, and should not change the question. There's certainly a case that your updated question was worthy of a brand new question, but I think I have made question and answers coherent now so I'd just leave the question as it stands now.

Comment: Sorry :( my problem was this, i tried to ask semplify much. was asked to post full code, so i take real code where i have worked and semplify too it reprocuding error. I ask you sorry too for my english. I understood before to delete from "new answer" and paste it on question, if i have mistaked, i ask you sorry again.

Comment: It's fine. I'm just trying to help by explaining how things should be done. Another point I would like to make is that you have asked 33 questions now yet only voted 4 times. Could I encourage you to participate more fully by voting more. Finally, did my answer resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes i finally understood where was mine error. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** This answer refers to the updated question.

In your updated code you simply do not create `oDBEstr` before you access it. The constructor of `TX2.Create` does not create it, and the class that `TX2` is derived from does not have a constructor. So naturally an access violation occurs.

The intent of these classes appears to be that `TX1` and hence `TX2` hold a *reference* to a `DBEstr` that is *owned* by a different class. You have implemented a read/write property that allows users of `TX1` and `TX2` to set this reference. However, they can't do so until the constructor has finished running. The users of `TX1` and `TX2` can only set that property once they have a reference to a `TX1` or `TX2`. So, to solve the conundrum your only option is to pass the `DBEstr` instance to the constructor of `TXE2` as a parameter.

Here's a working version of your code this illustrates how to do this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;

// Module 1

type
  PDBEstr = Integer;  // Just an example of list with integer
  TDBEstr = TList<PDBEstr>;

  TArchive = class
  protected
    oDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read oDBEstr;
  end;

constructor TArchive.Create;
begin
  oDBEstr := TList<PDBEstr>.Create;
  oDBEstr.Add(36);  // Add an element to list
end;

destructor TArchive.Destroy;
begin
  oDBEstr.Free;
  inherited;
end;

// Module 2

type
  TX0 = class
  protected
    oArchive: TArchive;
    function GetDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read GetDBEstr;
  end;

constructor TX0.Create;
begin
  oArchive := TArchive.Create;
end;

destructor TX0.Destroy;
begin
  oArchive.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TX0.GetDBEstr: TDBEstr;
begin
  Result := oArchive.DBEstr;
end;

// Module 3

type
  TX1 = class
  var
    oDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read oDBEstr write oDBEstr;
    procedure Load;
  end;

procedure TX1.Load;
begin
  writeln (oDBEstr.Count);  // Return 1
end;

// Module 4

type
  TX2 = class(TX1)
  public
    constructor Create(ADBEstr: TDBEstr);
  end;

constructor TX2.Create(ADBEstr: TDBEstr);
begin
  inherited Create;
  oDBEstr := ADBEStr;
  writeln(oDBEstr.Count);
end;

// Main Program

var
  X0: TX0;
  X2: TX2;
begin
  try
    X0 := TX0.Create;
    try
      writeln(X0.DBEstr.Count);  // Return 1
      writeln(X0.DBEstr.First);  // Return 36
      X2 := TX2.Create(X0.DBEstr);
      try
        writeln(X2.DBEstr.count);  // Return 1
      finally
        X2.Free;
      end;
    finally
      X0.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

I realise that this code is an illustrative example culled from your real code but I question the use of a read/write property for `TX1.DBEstr`. I suspect that each instance of `TX1` will use the same `DBEstr` instance for the entire lifetime of the `TX1` instance. If so then it should be passed in to a constructor on `TX1` and the property made read-only:

```
type
  TX1 = class
  var
    oDBEstr: TDBEstr;
  public
    constructor Create(ADBEstr: TDBEstr);
    property DBEstr: TDBEstr read oDBEstr;
    procedure Load;
  end;

constructor TX1.Create(ADBEstr: TDBEstr);
begin
  inherited Create;
  oDBEstr := ADBEStr;
end;
```

This change would lead to the following implementation for `TX2`

```
type
  TX2 = class(TX1)
  public
    constructor Create(ADBEstr: TDBEstr);
  end;

constructor TX2.Create(ADBEstr: TDBEstr);
begin
  inherited;
  writeln(oDBEstr.Count);
end;
```

---

Note as an aside that I have fixed the destructors in your code. Destructors should always be called `Destroy`, they should always be declared with the `override` keyword, and the should always call `inherited` as their final action. Note that you never call `Destroy` directly, rather you call `Free`. This convention is to enable `Free` to be a null operation on an uninitialized `nil` object reference which is a great convenience when coding destructors.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer refers to the original question.

The local variable `MyList` has not been created in the section of code that you label *main program*. Accordingly the object reference will have some garbage value from the stack. When you first come to access the list an access violation occurs.

Comment: I have omissed about MyList, why in full code it is correctly created from other class. I have tried too to add it, but so i receive again a exception: "Invalid pointer operation".

Comment: @Marcello You can't expect us to debug your code and then not show us the code. My answer is perfectly reasonable given the question you asked. If your real code is different, please show us that real code.

Comment: sorry for have take time, i have posted the real code under. Thanks again.